# Scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner was not configured, when used from a referenced library

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class which uses `org.reflections.Reflections` to get annotations in classes in the class path.

When i use it in the same project everything works fine, but when i export it as a JAR and refer it in a different class i get the below execption:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.reflections.ReflectionsException: Scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner was not configured
    at org.reflections.Store.get(Store.java:39)
    at org.reflections.Store.get(Store.java:61)
    at org.reflections.Store.get(Store.java:46)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Reflections.java:429)
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
        System.out.println("Package to Scan: "+getPackageName());
        final Reflections reflections = new Reflections(getPackageName(), new TypeAnnotationsScanner());
        final Set<Class<?>> handlerClasses = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(HandlerMapping.class,true);
```

I do provide a `TypeAnnotationsScanner` object, but still issue persists.

Note: It does not work only when above code is referred as a jar. (I created a fat jar using maven-assembly plugin)

Any pointers?

Comment: I am facing the same issue with `reflections` version `0.9.12`. In `0.9.11` I don't have such problems

Comment: Ok, I will check it works for me on .11

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Update 4 October 2021:**

This bug was fixed in version 0.10.

**Previous answer:**

Maybe not the type of answer one wants to hear but `reflections` version `0.9.12` contains a bug described here: https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections/issues/273

The bugfix has been provided in this PR (not merged yet): https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections/pull/278

The major difference between version `0.9.11` and `0.9.12` is that in `0.9.12` Guava dependency was removed in favor of Java 8 Streams API.

If you need to include this dependency without Guava transitive dependency, you may look at the next project: https://github.com/aschoerk/reflections8
Currently, the latest available version of `reflections8` is `0.11.7`.
Notice, `reflections8` is now considered to be obsolete due to `0.9.12` release of `reflections` but their version `0.11.7` doesn't contain this bug and this version doesn't depend on Guava. So, a possible solution would be to switch to `net.oneandone.reflections8:reflections8:0.11.7`.

Comment: Looks like the only way ahead till the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 8):

Using 0.9.12 of the reflections library I found registering the Scanner for each ElementType of the annotation was required.

MyAnnotation has these ElementTypes

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE,ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface MyAnnotation {
```

And in my reflections code I construct it like this

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.package.*",
        new SubTypesScanner(),
        new TypeAnnotationsScanner(),
        new FieldAnnotationsScanner());

//FieldAnnotationsScanner
Set<Field> fields =  reflections.getFieldsAnnotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class);
System.out.println(fields);
```

Answer (score 1):

Usage of Reflections8 didn't work for me, but on the page https://www.baeldung.com/reflections-library I found a solution, which worked in my case. When a resource scanner is provided in the constructor, Reflections found the resources:

```
 Reflections reflections = new Reflections("de.my_company",new ResourcesScanner());
 Set<String> foundResources = reflections.getResources(Pattern.compile(".*.xml"));

 for (String foundResource:foundResources) {
     System.out.println(foundResource);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

this works for me:
new Reflections(packageName, new TypeAnnotationsScanner());